# Direct access to NestJS DI container

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm working with NestJS for 4 month, and previously was working with PHP for 5 years.
With PHP and Symfony in particular I had an option to access compiled DI container and get any service from it for my need.

Like if we have an application with services (`A B C`) and `A` is dependent of `B` and `C` I was able to call for container in controllers and even in other services, which are aware of container, and use compiled `A` or `C` services for my needs.

Is there any option like this with NestJS DI - call certain service by some ID? I tried to search for it but everything ends up in using compiled services only with no direct access.

UPD: I'm interested in accessing DI container from a non-@Injectible class. For example:

```
export class StatefulCruncherClass{

    constructor(private dataToCrunch:any){
          
    }

    async crunch(){
        if (this.dataToCrunch.isObject){
             return NestJs.getDI().get('ObjectsCruncher').crunch(this)
        } else {
             return NestJs.getDI().get('ArrayCruncher').crunch(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `moduleRef` for this ([docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref))

```
@Injectable()
export class CatsService implements OnModuleInit {
  private service: Service;
  constructor(private moduleRef: ModuleRef) {}

  onModuleInit() {
    this.service = this.moduleRef.get(Service);
  }
}
```

Trying to access the container in a static (non injected) context seems suspicious to me and I think it likely points to a design/architecture issue for the feature you're trying to build. You're definitely "fighting" the framework at that point.

What is the reason that you need to have access in a non injectable way?

Your only other option would be somehow make the actual Nest application instance available to be imported into other files but I would strongly advise against it.

Comment: Thanks for response! It's close to what I need but I missed important detail in question. Added UPD  section

Comment: @Tesmen I don't think there is any answer for what you're trying to accomplish that isn't extremely hacky. You could update your question to provide some more context as to why you're even trying to accomplish this in the first place and I might be able to provide some additional approaches for you to consider